# Como fazer minha calculadora não repetir o sinal? JS

Tags: javascript, matemática

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Parte HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Calculadora</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input disabled type="text" name="" id="caixinha" placeholder="Vamos calcular" />
    <p>
      <input type="button" value="C" id="apagar"   onclick="mostrarNaTela(value)" />
      <input type="button" value="()" onclick="mostrarNaTela(value)" />
      <input type="button" value="/" onclick="mostrarNaTela(value)" />
      <input type="button" value="*" onclick="mostrarNaTela(value)" />
    </p>

    <p>
      <input type="button" value="7" onclick="mostrarNaTela(7)" />
      <input type="button" value="8" onclick="mostrarNaTela(8)" />
      <input type="button" value="9" onclick="mostrarNaTela(9)" />
      <input type="button" value="-" onclick="mostrarNaTela(value)" />
    </p>

    <p>
      <input type="button" value="4" onclick="mostrarNaTela(4)" />
      <input type="button" value="5" onclick="mostrarNaTela(5)" />
      <input type="button" value="6" onclick="mostrarNaTela(6)" />

      <input type="button" value="+" onclick="mostrarNaTela(value)" />
    </p>

    <p>
      <input type="button" value="1" onclick="mostrarNaTela(1)" />
      <input type="button" value="2" onclick="mostrarNaTela(2)" />
      <input type="button" value="3" onclick="mostrarNaTela(3)" />
      <input type="button" value="=" id="igualdade"  />
    </p>

    <input type="button"  value="0" onclick="mostrarNaTela(0)" />
    <input type="button" value="." onclick="mostrarNaTela(value)" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Parte JS:

```
var caixinha = document.getElementById("caixinha");

/* Função que mostra os números no Input de texto*/
function mostrarNaTela(mostrar) {
  if (caixinha.value == "*") {
    caixinha.value = "";
  }
  caixinha.value += mostrar;
  console.log(mostrar);
  console.log(caixinha.value);
}

/* Eventos de Clique pra cada ação mais específica*/
apagar.addEventListener("click", () => {
  caixinha.value = "";
});

igualdade.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (caixinha.value == "" || caixinha.value.length == 1) {
    alert("não vai rolar");
  } else {
    caixinha.value = eval(caixinha.value);
  }
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Para prevenir que exista dois determinados caracteres iguais um em seguida do outro você pode fazer uma condição que verifica se ele já foi digitado da ultima vez ou não.

Para verificar se determinado sinal ou caractere foi digitado, você pode utilizar RegEx (Expressões Regulares), com os valores de filtro. No seu caso ["+", "-", "/" e "*"].

##### REGEX

Para criar esse RegEx deve ter em mente suas necessidades,

- Verificar se o ultimo caractere da operação é um sinal ou não.

O Regex para essa solução ficaria assim: `/[\+\-\*\/]$/`.

1. Utilizamos `/` no inicio e no final para indicar o Regex;
2. Para identificar os caracteres que queremos checar, devemos colocar eles entre colchetes `[]`, para não dar conflito colocamos `\` antes dos caracteres, ficamos então assim: `[\+\-\*\/]`
3. O `$` no final, indica que queremos checar se existe os caracteres dentro dos colchetes apenas no ultimo valor da String.

##### LÓGICA

Agora podemos utilizar o regex para criar a lógica que só ira permitir o input de um novo valor **se o ultimo digito não for sinal** ou **se o novo valor inputado não for sinal**

Então sua função ficara dessa forma:

```
function mostrarNaTela(mostrar) {
        const regexSinais = new RegExp(/[\+\-\*\/]$/);
        const ultimoCaractereSinal = regexSinais.test(caixinha.value);
        const valorDigitadoSinal = regexSinais.test(mostrar);    
        
        if (!ultimoCaractereSinal || !valorDigitadoSinal) {
          if (caixinha.value == "*") {
            caixinha.value = "";
          }
          caixinha.value += mostrar;
          console.log(mostrar);
          console.log(caixinha.value);
        }
    }
```

Para ter certeza que esse código deve funcionar podemos fazer uma tabela verdade:

##### TABELA VERDADE

| Ultimo caractere não sinal | Caractere novo não sinal | Resultado "OU" |
| --- | --- | --- |
| VERDADE | VERDADE | VERDADE |
| FALSO | VERDADE | VERDADE |
| VERDADE | FALSO | VERDADE |
| FALSO | FALSO | FALSO |

Segundo nossa tabela verdade de **OU** não será possível adicionar um sinal quando o ultimo valor for sinal.

##### RESULTADO

```js
var caixinha = document.getElementById("caixinha");

/* Função que mostra os números no Input de texto*/
function mostrarNaTela(mostrar) {
    const regexSinais = new RegExp(/[\+\-\*\/]$/);
    const ultimoCaractereSinal = regexSinais.test(caixinha.value);
    const valorDigitadoSinal = regexSinais.test(mostrar);    
    
    if (!ultimoCaractereSinal || !valorDigitadoSinal) {
      if (caixinha.value == "*") {
        caixinha.value = "";
      }
      caixinha.value += mostrar;
      console.log(mostrar);
      console.log(caixinha.value);
    }
}

/* Eventos de Clique pra cada ação mais específica*/
apagar.addEventListener("click", () => {
  caixinha.value = "";
});

igualdade.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (caixinha.value == "" || caixinha.value.length == 1) {
    alert("não vai rolar");
  } else {
    caixinha.value = eval(caixinha.value);
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Calculadora</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input disabled type="text" name="" id="caixinha" placeholder="Vamos calcular" />
    <p>
      <input type="button" value="C" id="apagar"   onclick="mostrarNaTela(value)" />
      <input type="button" value="()" onclick="mostrarNaTela(value)" />
      <input type="button" value="/" onclick="mostrarNaTela(value)" />
      <input type="button" value="*" onclick="mostrarNaTela(value)" />
    </p>

    <p>
      <input type="button" value="7" onclick="mostrarNaTela(7)" />
      <input type="button" value="8" onclick="mostrarNaTela(8)" />
      <input type="button" value="9" onclick="mostrarNaTela(9)" />
      <input type="button" value="-" onclick="mostrarNaTela(value)" />
    </p>

    <p>
      <input type="button" value="4" onclick="mostrarNaTela(4)" />
      <input type="button" value="5" onclick="mostrarNaTela(5)" />
      <input type="button" value="6" onclick="mostrarNaTela(6)" />

      <input type="button" value="+" onclick="mostrarNaTela(value)" />
    </p>

    <p>
      <input type="button" value="1" onclick="mostrarNaTela(1)" />
      <input type="button" value="2" onclick="mostrarNaTela(2)" />
      <input type="button" value="3" onclick="mostrarNaTela(3)" />
      <input type="button" value="=" id="igualdade"  />
    </p>

    <input type="button"  value="0" onclick="mostrarNaTela(0)" />
    <input type="button" value="." onclick="mostrarNaTela(value)" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```